# Did Chumhum drop Florrick-Agos as their law firm in "The Debate"? If so, how does "Dark Money" make sense?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-wife

In the 6th season of *The Good Wife*, I believe in the episode titled "The Debate" (or a nearby episode), Florrick/Agos' largest client, Neil Gross, the owner of Chumhum, says he is leaving them after them seeming to lose him a lot of money in a divorce/publicity negotiation. Agos and Diane decide they need to get David Lee (the opposing lawyer in that negotiation) to join the firm after that, and they do.

In the next episode, "Dark Money", a case hinges on the discovery that the Chumhum home page appears on various computer screens in a TV show, for which they threaten to sue on behalf of Chumhum.

So I wonder, did Chumhum drop Florrick-Agos as their law firm, or not? If so, were they bluffing about suing on behalf of Chumhum in "Dark Money"? If not, why not? Did hiring David somehow get Chumhum to stay with the firm? Wouldn't that be a conflict of interest anyway since David represents Chumhum's owner's (ex-?)wife against him?